Issue with Incorrect Chemical Formula Identification in C
I'm developing a C program to identify and count chemical elements in formulas. The code was working perfectly fine for handling groups like (SO4)3, but I'm encountering issues with interpreting numeric coefficients before elements or groups, such as 2Fe or 5H2S. I modified the identifyCompound function to try to handle numeric coefficients before compounds or elements, but the result is not correct.
The void function works for the input: Fe + H2SO4 = Fe2(SO4)3 + H2S + H2O
But it fails for the input: 2Fe + 2H2SO4 = 2Fe2(SO4)3 + 2H2S + 2H2O
// Function to identify and count elements in a compound
void identifyCompound(char *input) {
    int length = strlen(input);
    int i = 0;
    Element elements[100]; // Array to store identified elements
    int numElements = 0;

    while (i < length) {
        if (isupper(input[i])) {
            // Found an element symbol
            char symbol[3] = {input[i], '\0'}; // Initialize symbol with uppercase letter
            int j = i + 1;

            // Check for lowercase letters (indicating part of the symbol)
            while (j < length && islower(input[j])) {
                strncat(symbol, &input[j], 1); // Concatenate lowercase letters to symbol
                j++;
            }

            // Check for a number (atom quantity)
            int quantity = 1;
            if (j < length && isdigit(input[j])) {
                sscanf(&input[j], "%d", &quantity); // Read number as integer
                while (j < length && isdigit(input[j])) {
                    j++; // Move past the number
                }
            }

            // Store the identified element
            strcpy(elements[numElements].symbol, symbol);
            elements[numElements].quantity = quantity;
            numElements++;

            i = j - 1; // Update the main index
        } else if (input[i] == '(') {
            // Beginning of a group enclosed in parentheses
            int j = i + 1;
            int start = j;

            // Find the end of the parentheses group
            int depth = 1;
            while (j < length && depth > 0) {
                if (input[j] == '(') {
                    depth++;
                } else if (input[j] == ')') {
                    depth--;
                }
                j++;
            }

            int end = j - 1;

            // Check for a number (coefficient) after the parentheses group
            int coefficient = 1;
            if (j < length && isdigit(input[j])) {
                sscanf(&input[j], "%d", &coefficient); // Read number as integer
                while (j < length && isdigit(input[j])) {
                    j++; // Move past the number
                }
            }

            // Process the parentheses group
            int k = start;
            while (k < end) {
                if (isupper(input[k])) {
                    char symbol[3] = {input[k], '\0'}; // Initialize symbol with uppercase letter
                    int m = k + 1;

                    // Check for lowercase letters (indicating part of the symbol)
                    while (m < end && islower(input[m])) {
                        strncat(symbol, &input[m], 1); // Concatenate lowercase letters to symbol
                        m++;
                    }

                    // Check if the element has a coefficient
                    int elementCoefficient = 1;
                    if (m < end && isdigit(input[m])) {
                        sscanf(&input[m], "%d", &elementCoefficient); // Read number as integer
                        while (m < end && isdigit(input[m])) {
                            m++; // Move past the number
                        }
                    }

                    // Store the element from the group with its quantity multiplied by the group's coefficient
                    strcpy(elements[numElements].symbol, symbol);
                    elements[numElements].quantity = coefficient * elementCoefficient;
                    numElements++;

                    k = m; // Update index to the next element
                } else {
                    k++; // Move to the next character
                }
            }

            i = j - 1; // Update the main index
        }

        i++; // Move to the next character
    }

    // Build and display the identified elements
    printf("Identified elements:\n");
    int totalAtoms = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < numElements; k++) {
        if (elements[k].quantity > 1) {
            printf("%s%d", elements[k].symbol, elements[k].quantity);
        } else {
            printf("%s", elements[k].symbol);
        }
        if (k < numElements - 1) {
            printf(" + ");
        }
        totalAtoms += elements[k].quantity;
    }
    printf("\nTotal atoms in the formula: %d\n", totalAtoms);
}

So I made some changes to the code to identify whether the compound or element has a numeric coefficient before it.
int currentCoefficient = 1; // Initialize the current coefficient as 1

// Check if the current character is a digit (isdigit(entrada[i])). If it is, this indicates a numeric coefficient is present before the next element or compound.
if (isdigit(entrada[i])) {
    // Found a numeric coefficient
    sscanf(&entrada[i], "%d", &currentCoefficient); // Read the number as an integer

    // Move past the number to continue reading the formula
    while (i < comprimento && isdigit(entrada[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    i--; // Move back an index to continue reading correctly
}

// When an element is identified (an element symbol is found), the code now stores this element along with the currentCoefficient applied.
// Store the identified element with the current coefficient
strcpy(elementos[numElementos].simbolo, symbol);
elementos[numElementos].quantidade = currentCoefficient;
numElementos++;

// When a group in parentheses is identified, the code also checks if there is a numeric coefficient immediately after the group. This coefficient is used to multiply the quantity of each element within that group.
// Process the group in parentheses with its coefficient
int groupCoefficient = 1;
if (j < comprimento && isdigit(entrada[j])) {
    sscanf(&entrada[j], "%d", &groupCoefficient); // Read the number as an integer
    while (j < comprimento && isdigit(entrada[j])) {
        j++; // Move past the number
    }
}

// Store the element from the group with its quantity multiplied by the group's coefficient
elementos[numElementos].quantidade = currentCoefficient * groupCoefficient;

For example, 2Fe is an element that has a numeric coefficient of 2 before Fe, but 2H2S is not an element; it's a compound with a numeric coefficient of 2 before it.
Below is the main code, remember to include the void function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Structure to represent a chemical element with atom count
typedef struct {
    char symbol[3]; // Element symbol (up to 2 characters for symbol + 1 for '\0')
    int quantity;   // Quantity of atoms of this element in the formula
} Element;


int main() {
    char input[100];

    printf("Enter an element or compound:\n");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    // Remove newline character (if present) from the input
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

    identifyCompound(input);

    return 0;
}



One piece: strncat(symbol, &input[j], 1); is an expensive way to copy one character, and doing this is NOT giving you a "null terminated string" for later use with strcpy(). Is this, perhaps, too ambitious a project for the level you've achieved so far?

If you are asking for stage-by-stage help, please link to your previous question(s) in this case, 12 hours earlier. Just makes life easier for everyone. (Here, it appears you want to transition from outputting fragments to buffering segments.)

Okay, @Fe2O3 I'll add the link to the previous question.
Quite ambitious, the code is actually much larger (I intend to balance simple equations), but when I realized that these coefficients before the compounds were not being counted, I had to revert to version 0.0, which is addressed in the above question. However, if with your help I can't achieve this, I'll leave it as it is and continue building the linear system. version0.4

Your prev Q show you accepted an A that recommends (in my words) "Don't store character arrays of elements' names. Use, for instance, enum { eH = 1, eHe, eLi, eBe, eB, ...". A program is free to use whatever it needs to for its internal data representation. This Q shows no sign of you having acted on that advice... Instead, you've introduced the source of THIS problem by changing printf() to incorrect use/understanding of strncat()... You need to cooperate & work together with people who try to provide help...

(1) Your function is TOO BIG. Break it up into smaller functions each doing one small well-defined thing.  (2) You are writing a parser for the language of chemical formulas. It is therefore absolutely necessary to write down the grammar of the language.

@Fe2O3 I managed to solve it, including with this example 2Na(H2(SO3)4)5

@UnsignedIndex Good for you. Consider this if you think others might be interested in your Q&A.

@UnsignedIndex If you feel inclined, consider posting your code to the SO Code Review site for it to be assessed. Usually some good recommendations for improvements from those readers...
